# Why does read() return 0 when I read from /dev/Channel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I tried to use the function `read()` to read from the channel device where I receive data. The data is returned irregularly.

The device driver that controls the channel is designed to wake up and sleep those which are waiting for reads on the channel device.

When the channel device does not have any data, the user thread sleeps and waits for the user to wake up; when the external agent writes in this memory associated with the channel, the user thread is activated and can read the data.

I use a `for (;;)` loop to constantly read the channel because when it reads the data, `read () returns 0`.

Example:

```
int ret, fd, receive;
fd = open("/dev/Channel_Normal0", O_RDWR, 0);
for(;;)
{
   printf("Try to read /dev/Channel_Normal0...\n\n");
   ret = read(fd, &receive, (sizeof(int)*4)); 
   printf("read for Channel_Normal0...\n\n");

   if(ret == 0)
     exit(0);
}
```

Why does it`return 0` if it reads the information? Because I can use the information I read.

PS: And, how can I know how many bytes I've actually read?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code needed to recreate you problem.

Comment: Thank @AndrewHenle

Comment: It would be useful to know something else about that device, put the output of ls -l /dev/Channel_Normal0, for example.

Comment: Since you appear to be running on Linux, you can see the results of the system calls your process makes with [the `strace` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).  A command such as `strace -f -o /path/to/your/output/file /your/dev/reader` should show all the system calls your process makes, and the result of them.  And this code is a problem:  `   ret = read(fd, &receive, (sizeof(int)*4));` since you're only reading *one* `int` value, it should be `ret = read(fd, &receive, sizeof(int));`, or even better `ret = read(fd, &receive, sizeof(receive));`.

Comment: `read()` also returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.

Comment: `read` syscall should return number of bytes which has been read (copired into destination buffer). Returning 0 means EOF (no more bytes in the file). These are "common" conventions, but specific driver may follow its own conventions.. or follow common conventions but has an implementation error. If you ask us **why the device driver behaves** in some way, we need to know more about the device and its driver (if the device and the driver aren't well-known ones).